# Rails 3 - Asset Pipe - Caching assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am having very slow page load time in DEVELOPMENT.

Already did `config.assets.digest = true` and `config.assets.debug = false` to make rails generate only one CSS / JS file.

The problem is, all the assets are sent with caching set to NO.
So the browser keeps quiering for each and every asset (images/css/js)

Is there a way to make Rails3.1 set let the browser to cache all assets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some misconfiguration with 'Webrat', when using 'thin' with same settings, cache headers are set correctly

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you are upgrading an app and have not pasted in the correct settings for the various environment config files. When set correctly the browser will get a 304 not modified response.

A 304 has to be used in development because if you use far future headers (full caching mode) then the browser will never request the files at all.

Have a look at the [upgrading section](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails) of the Rails Guides as this will give the correct settings for your environment files.